# Linear transformation implicit formula

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb  R^2$

$f((1,2,3)) = (2,1)$ and $f((2,3,4)) = (2,4)$

How can I write the associated matrix?

I tried to write the matrix with the standard base:

$$(2,1) = v_1$$
$$(2,4) = v_2$$

$v_1 = 1*f(1,0,0) + 2*f(0,1,0) + 3*f(0,0,1)$
$v_2 = 2*f(1,0,0) + 3*f(0,1,0) + 4*f(0,0,1)$

1 2 3 | v_1

2 3 4 | v_2

which becomes

1 0 -1 | v_1 - 2v_2

0 1 2  | 2v_1 - v_2

x3 = t = 0

x1 = (2,1) - (4,8) = (-2,-7)

x2 = (4,2) - (2,4) = (2, -2)

At the end the associated matrix is:

-2 2 0

-7 -2 0

Which gives : f(x,y,z) = (-2x +2y, -7x-2y) which is wrong.

*Associated matrix should be:

-2 2 0

5 -2 0

Comment: $f(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^2$, you wrote the image of $f$ as a three dimensional object.

Comment: @alvinL sorry it is (-2x+2y,-7x-2y)

Comment: There is no "should be", though. $f$ is not determined on $\mathbb R^3$, hence its matrix is also not uniquely determined (w.r.t given bases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subset $\{(1,2,3),(2,3,4)\}$ is linearly independent. If we extend it to a basis, then the new basis vector can map to anything under $f$.

So let's say we have a basis $B$ in $\mathbb R^3$ $b_1 = (1,2,3)$, $b_2 = (2,3,4)$ and $b_3$ is anything as long as $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ is linearly independent.

In the target space, you can work with the standard basis $E =\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$. With respect to this choice of bases, the matrix is
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 2 & u \\ 1& 4&v \end{array}  \right), $$
where $f(b_3) = (u,0) + (0,v)$

---

We don't know how $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$. What we can work out is

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc|cc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 2& 3& 4 & 2 & 4 \end{array}  \right) \to \left( \begin{array}{ccc|cc} 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & -2 \\ 1& 0& -1 & -2 & 5 \end{array}  \right), $$
for instance. So if we take a basis $C = \{c_1=(1,0,-1), c_2=(0,1,2), c_3\}$, then with respect to $C$ and $E$ the matrix would be
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} -2 & 2 & u \\ 5& -2&v \end{array}  \right), $$
where again $f(c_3) = (u,v)$. In particular if $c_3\in\mathrm{Ker}f$, then you would get the matrix at the end of your post.